# If I install libbitcoin-explorer will it be seperate from other libbitcoin repositories?

Tags: libbitcoin

I am installing `libbitcoin-explorer` on a Raspberry Pi with the `./install.sh` script and I wonder if this does anything to my existing installation of `libbitcoin-system`.

Which files will be installed?

Also, I wonder what happened to my `bitcoind` process which is not visible any more under `top` and not accessible with `bitcoin-cli`. Is it possible it crashed because of the heavy load of the installation?

---

EDIT: Also, I did not yet succeed in running the script on my Raspberry and on a x64 architecture mini PC. Not sure if it works.